# Return COUNT of rows as part of Concat String in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(transactionID, '|', startStatus, '|', endStatus, '|', transactionType, '|', date) FROM db_transactions 
WHERE orgId = 2
ORDER BY date DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 13 ROWS ONLY
```

I cannot retrieve more than 1 column, so I am using CONCAT to get multiple columns in one result.
But I also need to get total number of items.

So basically I want to return COUNT(transactionID) as part of CONCAT string, I tried adding:

```
SELECT CONCAT(transactionID, '|', startStatus, '|', endStatus, '|', transactionType, '|', date, '|', COUNT(transactionID))
```

but that did not work.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: "I cannot retrieve more than 1 column" is this a client limitation?

Comment: `COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY transactionID)`?

Comment: @EzLo yes, for now so I need to work around that until that's resolved sometime in future, it's weird but it's a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a windowed `COUNT()` converted to `VARCHAR`:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(
        transactionID, 
        '|', 
        startStatus, 
        '|', 
        endStatus, 
        '|', 
        transactionType, 
        '|', 
        date,
        '|',
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY transactionID)))
FROM 
    db_transactions 
WHERE 
    orgId = 2
ORDER BY 
    date DESC
OFFSET 
    0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 
    13 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want for each `TransactionID` add up a *total count* of these id, you can try *analytical function* `COUNT() OVER (PARTITION BY)`:

```
  SELECT CONCAT(transactionID, '|', 
                  startStatus, '|', 
                    endStatus, '|', 
              transactionType, '|', 
                         date, '|', 
             COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY transactionID))
     ...
```